# How can an NSPredicate test that a value contains one of two other values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I'm trying to write an `NSPredicate` that expresses: "If uid contains myID OR targetUser"

However no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to want to work. How can I edit my line below to execute the above?

My current code:

```
 NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", myID];
```

I tried the following, but no dice:

```
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@ OR contains[cd] %@", myID, targetUser];
```

Comment: If you'd wrote it in "code" and not in a predicate, you'd write `if ([uid containsCD:myID] || (uid containsCD:targetUser])` not `if ([uid containsCD:myID || targetUser])`, where `containsCD:` is the equivalent of `contains[cd]`. Same logic for the predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uid contains[cd] %@) OR (uid contains[cd] %@)", myID, targetUser];`

Comment: In full line pls? Can't use the curved brackets inside my current line ?

Comment: @Brittany you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@ OR uid contains[cd] %@", myID, targetUser];
```